# How to close all the child pages on LogOut

Tags: javascript, asp.net

We have a Master page and some child pages.One in them is popup by window.open function.The problem occurs When logout is clicked at Master Page.whole System is redirect to Login page except that Popup window.when i clicked on that child-page  then it will redirected to Login Page.We need it be closed directly after logout is pressed.

Is there any script to close window if the window's location is known.I want to close that child page in Logout click.
like window.close('Authentication.aspx');
please tell me if it is possible

Thanks ,
Rakesh.

Answer (score 1):

If you've opened a popup window using the following code, with a presumed name of "popupwindow"...

```
window.open("myurl.html", "popupwindow", "height, etc");
```

Then in your login page try the following javascript

```
if(window.name=="popupwindow"){
  window.close();
}
```

**UPDATE** based on comments by OP...

If you no longer have a reference to the window (because the parent window has refreshed for example), then I believe it is almost impossible to detect whether a popup window with a particular name exists or not.

I say "almost impossible" because one option in this situation is to try opening the window again giving a blank URL. If the window already exists, then the window will remain on the same page as before, but now you have a reference to it, and can close as necessary.

```
var myWin = window.open("","popupwindow");
myWin.close();
```

However, the **downside to this** is that if the window does **not** exist, the user will see a blank window open before then being closed - so not a nice user-experience.

Comment: Hi freefaller......I tried this   but the opened window is not closing.Is there any way other than this

Comment: @rakesh, are you talking about closing the window at the point that the user clicks logout on the parent window?

Comment: yes freefaller....We are opening childwindow while login.need to close it on Logout click

Comment: @rakesh, unfortunately I think you're going to have difficultly with that one. As far as I'm aware it is impossible to detect if a window has been opened, and therefore close it. The only option (but it isn't a nice one) is to try opening a window with the same name. If one already exists then you will be able to close it - but it will result in a blank window being opened if the window **doesn't** already exist... so not a nice user-experience

Comment: Thank you Freefaller....I will try another way ,if it fails i will  tell to clients that will not possible .