# How to get window object by name in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

my query is, to close all child windows(if open) after logout. 
I am creating child window from different jsps & i want to close it from Search.jsp. 
Search.jsp has buttons like Create, Logout.

My Search.jsp is -

```
    <%
String sessionstart = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionstart");

if(sessionstart != null)
{
%>

<body>
        <div align="center" >   <img src="images/Headerimage.png" alt=""> </img></div>


        <div id = "leftmargin" >
        <form action="Search" method="post">
            <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
                <tr >
                    <td  >Type</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="type" value="*" required /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="name" value="*" required /></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;Description</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="description" value="*" required /></td>
                    <td></td><td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Search" /></td>

                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>

                    <td><h5>    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="Create();" /></h5>    </td>
   <td>  <h5>   <input type="button" value="Logout" onclick="Logout(); " /> </h5>    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

    <%
        if (sessionset != null) {
    %>
    <div align="center" style="margin-top: 15%">
        <img src="images/DocumentManagementSplash.png" alt=""> </img>
    </div>
    <%
        }
    %>
</body>

<% 
 }
else
{
%>
<script>
window.location.replace("ietmLoginDialog.jsp");
</script>
<%  
}
%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Create() {
        window.open("ltIEnterCreatePartFileUpload.jsp?", "CreatePart",
                "height=140,width=350");
    }

    function Logout() { 

    var w = document.getElementsByName("mywin");
    alert("w closed :: "+ w.closed);
    alert("w name :: "+ w.name);
    alert("w open:: "+ w.open); 

        if(w.name == "mywin"){
          w.close();
        }

        window.open("ietmLoginDialog.jsp", '_self', "location=yes");
    }

</script>
```

Here , if i click on the logout button, then it must close all the OPEN child windows.
The childs windows i am creating from different jsp's.
For example, from Search.jsp, I open property page ie.,

```
<td style="width: 170px;" ><a
                            href="ltSearchDocProperties.jsp?idvalue=<%=strObjectId%>"
                            onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin',
'left=20,top=20,width=900,height=725'); return false;"><%=strName%></a></td>
```

From Property.jsp, i open edit jsp ie.,

```
<h5 align="right"> 
<a href="ltSearchDocEdit.jsp?idvalue=<%=strObjectId%>" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywiirn','width=900,height=615,resizable=false'); return false;">Edit</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;</h5>
```

& likewise. 
As of my knowledge, I can achieve this if i am creating the child window from same jsp ie. Search.jsp only.

My readings are -

[How to close all the child pages on LogOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175930/how-to-close-all-the-child-pages-on-logout)

[How to Close multiple child windows from a parent window](http://www.coderanch.com/t/460745/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/Close-multiple-child-windows-parent)

Again this describes only if the window reference is in jsp only.
So please suggest me, How i can close all child windows, creating from different jsp's
from another jsp(Search.jsp) ?

Any advice or any other way to achieve this, will be very much helpful for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ÿou should remove the Java tag. Java has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: @HowardRenollet - you are right, must have been the monday blues :-) Usually i just leave a comment... (Downvote and comment undone)

Comment: @GyroGearless - thanks.  My comments removed too :)  Have a good rest of your day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `window.open()` returns a reference to the created window, you could store them in a variable, and close them on logout:

```
var windowsToCloseOnLogout = [];

function create() {
    windowsToCloseOnLogout.push(window.open("ltIEnterCreatePartFileUpload.jsp?", "CreatePart", "height=140,width=350"));
}

function logout() {
    for (var i = 0, windowNb = windowsToCloseOnLogout.length; i < windowNb ; i++) {
        windowsToCloseOnLogout[i].close();
    }
    window.open("ietmLoginDialog.jsp", '_self', "location=yes");
}
```

Comment: I got it. It will work if you are creating the child window from same jsp only. But How i can return the open window reference from different jsp's as mentioned in question ?